# How to dynamically add new queues (from different hosts) to @RabitListener?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I'm trying to have a @RabbitListener to listen to several queues from different hosts loaded from properties. the queues are identical and require the same message processing.

I managed to do it "statically" 
by declaring my factories like this :

```java
        @Bean
        public ConnectionFactory defaultConnectionFactory() {
          CachingConnectionFactory cf = new CachingConnectionFactory();
          cf.setAddresses(hosts);
          cf.setPort(port);
          cf.setUsername(username);
          cf.setPassword(password);
          cf.setConnectionLimit(10000);
     cf.getRabbitConnectionFactory().setConnectionTimeout(connectionTimeout);
        return cf;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory connectionFactory2() {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory sf = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        CachingConnectionFactory cf = new CachingConnectionFactory();
        cf.setAddresses(host2);
        cf.setPort(port2);
        cf.setUsername(username2);
        cf.setPassword(password2);
        cf.setConnectionLimit(connectionLimit);
        cf.getRabbitConnectionFactory().setConnectionTimeout(connectionTimeout);
        sf.setConnectionFactory(cf);
        return sf;
    }
```

And then adding @RabbitListener annotations to my listener class like so :

```java
@RabbitListener (queues = "q1")
@RabbitListener (queues = "q2" , containerFactory = "connectionFactory2")
public class RabbitListener {
```

But I would like to be able to create connection factories at startup by loading some property list like `rabbit.host[i]`and then dynamically add it to my listener.

Is such a thing possible ? What are the best practices for this use case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with static `@RabbitListener` annotations, but you can [register listener endpoints programmatically](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/_reference.html#async-annotation-driven-registration).

You can use a `SimpleRabbitListenerEndpoint` as shown there, or a `MethodRabbitListenerEndpoint` if you want to invoke a POJO method (like `@RabbitListener`.

You can wire in the appropriate factory in the overloaded `registerEndpoint` method.

Comment: I tried to play around with this but I need to have a different connection factory for each endpoint, when looking at the examples it seems that the endpoints are added with `registrar.registerEndpoint(endpoint);` and thus are on the same host. Or is there a way to register those endpoints on different registrars ?

Comment: I added a note to the end before the edit grace period - there is an overloaded `registerEndpoint` that takes a container factory as well.

Comment: Thank you for the information, it's very helpful. Last detail : is there a need for my connectionFactories to be beans or simple java object are sufficient  ?

Comment: They must be beans, to get full functionality (event publishing etc), unless you want to do all the Spring wiring yourself (satisfy the `...Aware` interfaces). You can, of course, programmatically register new instances with Spring using the `GenericApplicationContext.registerBean("container1", SRLCF.class, () -> instance)` and he will take care of the initialization.